# Disabling same-origin policy in Safari

Tags: safari, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

For development purposes, I need to disable the same-origin policy in Safari (on Windows) on my machine.

In Chrome, this can be done by launching with the flag `--disable-web-security`. Is there an equivalent flag or hidden setting in Safari?

Answer (score 108):

If you want to disable the same-origin policy on Safari (I have 9.1.1), then you only need to enable the developer menu, and select "Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions" from the develop menu.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You must to reload the webpage.

Comment: For Germans: "Ursprungsübergreifende Beschränkungen deaktivieren"

Comment: Does not work. In Safari 11.0.3 i Disable Cross-origin restrictions and still same.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This works for me with Safari 12.0.3. I also had to clear the cache (with Shortcut or in developer menu --> Empty Caches) + reload the webpage as from @TlmaK0 suggested.

Comment: I don't see how this is a "solution" when a huge percentage of the browser market is broken by AAPL. You can't expect millions of people to disable their security policy after reading StackOverflow. Frankly, this breaks 3rd party integrations and I might have to flush weeks of work down the toilet (and lots of troubleshooting between three companies) because of this.

Answer (score 49):

Later versions of **Safari** allow you to Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions. Just enable the developer menu from Preferences >> Advanced, and select "**Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions**" from the develop menu.

If you want **local** only, then you only need to enable the developer menu, and select "**Disable local file restrictions**" from the develop menu.

Comment: This menu item doesn't exist. I've checked Safari 6.0 and 6.0.2 on Mac OS X Lion, but as you can see [in this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iu0sH.png), there's not such an option called "Disable local file restrictions". [Apple's KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5364) (last edited 16 nov 2012) mentions this feature, but still, it does not exist.

Comment: This menu item is in the Develop menu which needs to be enabled in preferences under Advanced "Show Develop menu in menu bar".  But it doesn't seem to avoid the the cors issue.

Comment: Rob W: Down vote? I did say that you "need to enable the developer menu", and then you can select "Disable local file restrictions".

Comment: I'm running Safari 7 on Mavericks. Happy to say this still works.

Comment: The same origin policy and local file restrictions are not the same thing, this answer does not answer the question correctly.

Comment: you can turn off local file restrictions, but for testing cross-browser stuff with same-origin policy problems use firefox or chrome. For chrome and OS X see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/2526914

Comment: Please down vote this answer. This does not answer the question.

Comment: This answer seems to be helping some people with running local files. It won't help with CORS however. Rather than down voting, may I suggest you provide a solution that people can upvote?

Comment: I want to disable web security for safari in mac osx is it possible

Answer (score 11):

goto,

Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced

then at the bottom tick **Show Develop Menu in menu bar**

then in the Develop Menu tick **Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions**

Comment: It works with desktop safari but how to switch this option on mobile device?

Comment: not sure whether we have same option on mobile Safari. But Settings -> Safari -> Advanced you may find something

Comment: For mobile's iOS Safari, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari#72309627).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent for Safari and the argument `--disable-web-security` doesn't work with Safari.

If you have access to the server side application, you can modify the https response headers to allow access. Mainly the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Modifying it will allow Safari to access the resource. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin for more information on the response headers that will help.

Comment: Can confirm that sadly Safari has no command line arguments. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8044532

Answer (score 2):

There is an option to disable cross-origin restrictions in Safari 9, different from local file restrictions as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

For those debugging a site in iOS Safari with an iPhone plugged into a Mac and using the Mac's *Develop* menu to inspect the site on the phone, if the option for `Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions` is greyed out, follow these steps.

- Click on the *Safari* menu on your Mac
- Click on *Preferences...*
- Click on the tab for *Privacy*
- Remove the checkmark for *Prevent cross-site tracking*
- Refresh the page on your phone
- Put a sticky note on your computer with a reminder to put the checkmark back when you are done working

(Tested on iOS 15.3.1 and Desktop Safari 14.0.1)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, (ios15.3.x and macos 13.0.1, safari 16.1) the menu item is still greyed out. I have to click the little phone icon when inspecting and disable CORS from there (which does work)

Answer (score 1):

Most of these answers are old. The latest Safari 14.0.2 (in 2021), has the option to `Disable Cross-Origin Restrictions`, however, it doesn't work if the paths have ../../ kind of path names; even though Safari correctly resolves to a local file path, it still doesn't permit loading the file, even though it exists. This is a recent bug in Safari 14 that didn't happen in 13.

Answer (score 0):

For Safari 17, the menu item moved to a checkbox in Preferences -> Developer -> Disable cross-origin restrictions.