# Restangular prevent 'preflight' OPTIONS call

Tags: angularjs, rest, cors, restangular

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the OPTIONS call from firing on every GET call to our API server.

I'm trying this right now:

```
.config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({"X-Requested-With" :"", "Content-Type": "text/plain"});
})
```

But it's not doing me any good. Everything still thinks it's `application/json` so it fires off the preflight call. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What other headers is it sending?

Comment: It's sending up an `Authorization` token, and some caching stuff: `.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: cache});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

> OPTIONS requests are what we call pre-flight requests in Cross-origin
>   resource sharing (CORS).
>
> They are necessary when you're making requests across different
>   origins.
>
> This pre-flight request is made by some browsers as a safety measure
>   to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server.
>   Meaning the server understands that the method, origin and headers
>   being sent on the request are safe to act upon.
>
> Your server should not ignore but handle these requests whenever
>   you're attempting to do cross origin requests.

[How to disable OPTIONS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)