# Getting 401 Unauthorized on Post method [ Front end - Angular 2 & Back end - Cakephp 3]

Tags: angular, cors, jwt, cakephp-3.0

I am using Angular 2 for Front end & Back end in Cakephp 3. I am getting 401 Unauthorized status while I am trying to login. I have configured JWT in cakephp 3 and it is working fine in POSTMAN. But not working with Angular.

Here is my TypeScript code

```
loginToken(uname: string, pwd: string): Observable<boolean>{
  let json = JSON.stringify({ username: uname , password: pwd});
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/crm/crm/api/users/token', json, options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
      let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
      if (token) {
        this.token = token;
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: uname, token: token }));
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

Cakephp 3 code - server side

```
public function token()
    {   
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid username or password');
        }

        $this->set([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'token' => JWT::encode([
                    'sub' => $user['id'],
                    'exp' =>  time() + 604800
                ],
                Security::salt())
            ],
            '_serialize' => ['success', 'data']
        ]);

    }
```

Here are some screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]
Please help me out on this.

After removing options -

```
loginToken(uname: string, pwd: string): Observable<boolean>{
  let json = JSON.stringify({ username: uname , password: pwd});
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/crm/crm/api/users/token', json, {headers: headers })
    .map((response: Response) => {
      let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
      if (token) {
        this.token = token;
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: uname, token: token }));
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

and response I got

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue and something you will either need to configure on the server or something in the headers which is not quite right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Yes, I do feel same but not getting the solution for that, any suggestion ?

Comment: @NeerajRathod, have you fixed it and working fine? I am troubleshooting the same thing. I am trying to create login and registration functionality with cakephp 3.4.0 and Angular 2. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is missing or wrong content type header.

For login not to send OPTIONS requests your content type should be one of the standard form types:
      application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data

I think, text/pain might also work, but I didn't use it myself.

EDIT: actually there is a SO about it: [How to disable OPTIONS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)

Comment: Hi Vladimir M, I have tried with "Content-type :application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  but it is not working, any other suggestion ?

Comment: does it still send options request? You might also want to remove "accept" header from the request, if options are still sent.

Comment: No, I have removed options and pass headers object with 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.

Comment: can you update with the latest screen shot of that response from dev tools.

Comment: I have put latest screen shot of response, please go through it and share some suggestion waiting

Comment: I think that now your auth data is still json and server expects url-encoded form. In this blog there is an example of a post construction: [link](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129238/discussion-between-neeraj-rathod-and-vladimir-m).