# Why does each Ember data store transaction send additional OPTIONS requests to server?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data in my app, however, I realize that Ember data will make **two** separated requests (for example a `GET` and an `OPTIONS`) to the server which of course takes a longer time than making a single request.

See screenshot below, the `OPTIONS` requests take 1 second to complete and total 2 seconds for each user operation.

[image]

The code snippet below is what I used to fetch models in one particular route,

```
model() {
    return this.store.findAll('card');
},
```

My question is why it makes two requests? and is this necessary to make an `OPTIONS` request? If not how can I stop let my Ember data making `OPTIONS` request?

Comment: Can you shows us the exact code you use to fire the request? Are you using the Ember Data store?

Comment: I am using Ember data store and I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) that exists mainly because of security and is required when [dealing with CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS#Preflighted_requests_in_CORS).

The browser does this automatically to ensure that the request being done is trusted by the server.

There are two ways to disable it (or at least limit it):

1. By setting the [Access-Control-Max-Age](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Max-Age) header which will allow results of a preflight request to be cached and reduce the amount of requests.
2. Convert your request into a [simple request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests) which doesn't trigger a preflighted request.

A simple request is one that meets all the following conditions:

1. The only allowed methods are:

   - GET
   - HEAD
   - POST
2. The only headers allowed to be manually set are those which the [Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-request) defines as being a [CORS-safelisted request-header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header)

If your request uses any other method besides the ones above or sets a non CORS-safelisted header, it will be preflighted automatically.

---

For reference, the OPTIONS method is defined by the [HTTP method definitions RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) like:

> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)