# CORS issue with Serverless and PUT command

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am running into another CORS issue with Serverless and AWS. Seems I need to tell it specifically to allow a PUT method, but I am not sure where this code goes. I have the following code for my Lambda function:

```
module.exports.update = (event, context, callback) => {
  const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  if (typeof event.pathParameters.timeoffgroupid !== 'string') {
    console.error('Validation Failed');
    callback(new Error('Couldn\'t update the todo item.'));
    return;
  }
  const params = {
    TableName: 'TimeOffGroup',
    Key: {
      timeoffgroupid: event.pathParameters.timeoffgroupid,
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':timeOffGroup': data.timeOffGroup,
      ':timeOffGroupColor': data.timeOffGroupColor,
      ':dateModified': timestamp
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET timeOffGroup = :timeOffGroup, timeOffGroupColor = :timeOffGroupColor, dateModified = :dateModified',
    ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW',
  };

  dynamoDb.update(params, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
      callback(new Error('Couldn\'t update the todo item.'));
      return;
    }
    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(result.Attributes),
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
      }
    };
    callback(null, response);
  });
};
```

The error I am getting is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://pwqlomgq89.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/timeoffgroup/7d463800-0935-11e7-b618-4b1d72ddca8e?timeOffGroup=Holiday+edited.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 502. angular.js:14328
>   Possibly unhandled rejection:
>   {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"PUT","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","data":{},"url":"https://pwqlomgq89.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/timeoffgroup/7d463800-0935-11e7-b618-4b1d72ddca8e","params":{"timeOffGroup":"Holiday
>   edited"},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain,
>   */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":""}

I have followed all of the calls on serverless tutorials to get the CORS to work. But it seems I got the get and create to work, but the PUT command is not working. Is there some place I need to still set the update command to allow PUT for cross domain?

Looks like I might need more here for a PUT method access:
headers:

```
{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", // Required for CORS support to work
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true
}
```

Comment: The reason you’re getting that particular error message is probably just that your server is not configured to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to server-error responses. The real underlying problem which that message indicates is that there’s a 502 error on the server side, which would seem to indicate some other failure is happening that’s unrelated to your CORS configuration. So you probably want to look through you server logs to get more details about what’s causing that 502 server failure so you can fix that. It could be something as simple as minor syntax error

Comment: Yeah I looked at the server logs, it is saying "ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :timeOffGroupColor" Looking through for typo now.

Comment: I have an undefined value in javascript being passed into the function. I can clear this up now, thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is that you don't handle the `OPTIONS` verb. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954326/1476885) to understand more about this requirement.

Before making the `PUT` request, the browser will preflight an `OPTIONS` request as a safety measure to ensure that this kind of request is expected by the server. If you don't support `OPTIONS`, it won't make the `PUT` request.

To fix this, change your **serverless.yml** file to add `OPTIONS` support.

```
functions:
  func:
    handler: handler.func
    events:
      - http: PUT foo/bar
      - http: OPTIONS foo/bar
```

Modify your handle with something like this:

```
module.exports.func = (event, context, callback) => {

  try {
    switch(event.httpMethod + ' ' + event.resource) {
      case 'PUT /foo/bar':
        handlePut(callback);
        break;
      case 'OPTIONS /foo/bar':
        handleOptions(callback);
        break;
      default:
        // return HTTP 400
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
     // return HTTP 500
  }
};

const handlePut = (callback) => {
    callback(null, { 
        statusCode: 200, 
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }, 
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'PUT'
        })
    });
};

const handleOptions = (callback) => {
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, content-type, accept',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by increasing the time out in lambda. This fixes CORS problem of mine.