# Send 2 ajax POST request on single click

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

[image]

```js
logout(){
  var destroySession='{"token":"'+this.token+'"}'
  console.log("Session Destroy"+destroySession)
  axios.post(eventBus.apiURL+'logout',{
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: destroySession,
  }).then(response=>{
    console.log("RESadas :: "+JSON.stringify(response.data))        
    alert("Logout successfully..!")
    this.$router.push('/')       
  },error=>{
    console.log(error);
    alert("Some Issue for LogOut at Server Side..!")
    
  });
 

  window.localStorage.removeItem('token')
  window.localStorage.removeItem('name')
  this.$router.push('/')
}
```

```html
<button @click="logout">Logout</button>
```

I have written a code for logout in `vuejs`, but at the time of click it sends two `POST` request and during session destroy problem occurs at server side.

Comment: So you want to send 2 requests to the server or you have a problem because 2 requests are being send to the server? If it is the latter you could add the attribute 'disabled' to the button when the first request begins.

Comment: The problem is 2 requests are being send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests),

> **Preflight Requests**
>
> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), "preflighted" requests
> first send an HTTP request by the OPTIONS method to the resource on
> the other domain, in order to determine whether the actual request is
> safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this since they
> may have implications to user data.
>
> In particular, a request is preflighted if any of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> If the request uses any of the following methods:
>
> - Put
> - DELETE
> - CONNECT
> - OPTIONS
> - TRACE
> - PATCH
>
> Or if, apart from the headers set automatically by
> the user agent (for example, Connection, User-Agent, or any of the
> other header with a name defined in the Fetch spec as a “forbidden
> header name”), the request includes any headers other than those which
> the Fetch spec defines as being a “CORS-safelisted request-header”,
> which are the following:
>
> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type (but note the additional requirements below)
> - DPR
> - Downlink
> - Save-Data
> - Viewport-Width
> - Width
>
> Or if the Content-Type header has a
> value other than the following:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

**Updated**

Please read this answer on how to disable preflight requests: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954037/4461764)

Comment: What you suggest to send one request bye using POST?

Comment: Your function is only sending one post request. First one is just a check that the post request is safe to send.

Comment: If you see the second request than you will come to know that the request data is being sent on that request only.

Comment: how can I avoid that preflight request?
is their any way to avoid this request for the POST method