# Two calls on Post request: with http 204 and 200

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, .net-core

I have implemented  Cors policy in dot net core application:
  In `Startup.cs` under `ConfigureServices` I have added the following cors policy

```
services.AddCors(options =>{
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

I'm facing a strange issue after adding CORS policy, on every POST call from UI there are two calls made: first calls returns with 204 and other call returns the data with 200 status code.

[image: two calls on post request]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First one is a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request). The main goal is to determinate whether the actual request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted since they may have implications to user data.

> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood.
>
> It is an `OPTIONS` request using two HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.
>
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser when needed.

This [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) describe conditions that if true then request is preflighted.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this pre-flight calls? I'm using angularjs on the front-end.

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe look into SO  [How to disable OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/how-to-disable-options-request)

Comment: have the same 'issue'. Now it makes sense. I was debugging my Angular code, if there somehow was 2 calls

Comment: So the `204 No Content` request is the CORS preflight request?