# Firebase Cloud Functions https.onCall finished with status code: 204

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

**Firebase Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { text: "Test" };
});
```

**Issue**

The problem is when i call this function from the app i first get **finished with status code: 204** and after that **finished with status code: 200**

[204](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8brI.png)

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is normal, and you shouldn't do anything to prevent it.  The first request that results in 204 is what happens when CORS performs a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).  The 200 is the final serviced request.

You can read more about that here:

[Two calls on Post request: with http 204 and 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544064/two-calls-on-post-request-with-http-204-and-200)

Comment: Does this mean an .onCall takes 2 function executions from your quotum?

Comment: @JaapWeijland Yes, when adding cors support, this is the case for both callable and regular HTTP functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson, strange, I don't have any CORS and yet I am getting this. it's a simple vanilla onCall function

Comment: @TheeBen CORS is default in most browsers. It's actually harder to disable it.