# Axios is preventing other methods from being executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, axios

I have a form in a modal that I want to close right after submitting.  The form works perfectly fine and the data input from the form gets reflected on the database, but the rest of the actions within the same method doesn't get triggered for some reason.

I want the form to execute when the submit button is pressed :

1) change the `loading` to true through `setLoading(true)

2) post the input data

3) close the modal

Currenly, 1) and 3) aren't being carried out.  `closeModal` works fine if I comment out the `axios`.

Following is the modal:

```
const Form = ({ closeModal }) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        setLoading(true)                
        e.preventDefault()    
        try {
            await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createEmailList`, {
                email,
                firstName,
                lastName
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
            closeModal()                        
        }
    }

    return (
        <form 
            className="form"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
            <div className="label">Name *</div>
            <div className="desc">What is your name?</div> 
            <div className="input-container">
                <label className="label">
                    <input 
                        className="input" 
                        type="text" 
                        value={firstName} 
                        onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)} 
                    />
                    <div className="desc">First Name</div>
                </label>
                <label className="label">
                    <input 
                        className="input"
                        type="text" 
                        value={lastName} 
                        onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)} 
                    />
                    <div className="desc">Last Name</div>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="label">Email Address *</div>
            <div className="input-container">
                <label className="label">
                    <input 
                        className="input2" 
                        type="email" 
                        value={email} 
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} 
                        required
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
            <button className="button">
                {loading ? "Loading..." : "Submit"}
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Also, I'm using Google Functions(Firebase) as the backend.

Update:

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
    setLoading(true)                
    e.preventDefault()    
    try {
        await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createEmailList`, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        })
    setLoading(false)
    closeModal() 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i think you should close model and loading false after getting response of axios not in finally. because finally will execute every time whether it's successful or not.

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar did you mean like the way I updated in the post?

Comment: i am saying like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637660/6544460

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close mode and make loading false in `then()` with resonse.

```
const handleSubmit = async e => {
      setLoading(true)                
      e.preventDefault()  
        await axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/createEmailList`, {
            email,
            firstName,
            lastName
        })
       .then(res=> { 
         if(res.status===204 || res.status===200){
           setLoading(false)
           closeModal()
          } 
       })
       .catch(err=> console.log(err));
    }
```

Comment: @Kevvv what problem are you facing? and check network tab while posting. let me know the problem

Comment: @your status code is 204 means no response after request completed.

Comment: apparently, this isn't an issue according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931587/firebase-cloud-functions-https-oncall-finished-with-status-code-204

Comment: @Kevvv can you console response in then() and check that. i think i might be possible you aren't getting status code from backend.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `finally` gets executed before async API call performs.

Perhaps, you could chain your axios call for `response` and `error` as

```
 await axios
    .post(`${ROOT_URL}/createEmailList`, {
        email,
        firstName,
        lastName
    })
    .then(response => {
        /*
        You could close modal and set loading to false here
        */
    })
    .catch(err => {
        /*
        catch errors
        */
    });
```

This will remove dependency for try-catch  block

Comment: Okay, but what's the issue you are facing ? Does it throw error?