# Google Cloud Function returning 204 status

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have been noticing some strange behavior from one of my google cloud functions. It is a callable cloud function that is being called from my firebase app. Whenever I test the function it works as expected, but when I look in the logs I see a bunch of 204 status codes. I have a console.log statement as the first line, but whenever it ends with 204 status, that first line never executes. I am a bit confused as to why this is happening and would love some feedback!

Runtime is Nodejs 16.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544064/two-calls-on-post-request-with-http-204-and-200

Those 204s are normal. Do you have any error messages or lines or code to share where you see logging stop working?

Comment: The Firebase SDK is automatically handling the required cors preflight request without invoking your code.  Your function will execute on the followup request.