# Cloud Functions for Firebase triggering function on CORS preflight request

Tags: javascript, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that validates inputs from a form submission on my client. I'm using Cloud Functions for Firebase [https triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with [cors express middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors).

**Firebase Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const validateImageForm = require('./library/validate-image-form');

exports.apiValidateImageForm = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  cors(req, res, () => {

    validateImageForm(req.body.formInputs, req.body.imageStatus).then((data) => {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    });

  });

});
```

**Client Call To Function**

```
const validateImageFormFetchOptions = {
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   method: 'POST',
   body: JSON.stringify({
     formInputs: formInputs
   })
}

fetch('https://project-url.cloudfunctions.net/apiValidateImageForm', validateImageFormFetchOptions)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(serverErrors => {console.log(serverErrors)});
```

**Issue**

When I call this function from my client using a fetch request I see two apiValidateImageForm triggers in the functions logs. The first is a status 204 and I assume this comes from the cors preflight request that checks the origin. The final request is status 200. I just want one function trigger when I fetch the apiValidateImageForm function. I'm concerned that over time the preflight requests that output the status 204 will add unnecessary function calls to my project quota.

[image]

**Question**

Is it possible to prevent firebase from triggering a function call on the preflight request? If not then is there a way to prevent the preflight request and successfully pass data to the function.

Comment: As long as you’re adding a `Content-Type': 'application/json'` header to the request, the browser is going to automatically on its own do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the request from your code. So the only way to avoid is that is to not send it encoded as application/json but to instead send the JSON as the value of a parameter in a request body with a application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type; that is, as name+value pair like `json=[your JSON data here]`. See the *How to avoid the CORS preflight* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/441757

Answer (score 11):

To fix the duplicate requests 200 and 204 then change how you're client side fetch request. @sideshowbarker is right. The browser automatically does the CORS preflight OPTIONS request so this is not an issue in Cloud Functions for Firebase. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30296149/3406865) was helpful.

To fix the preflight I changed my code to the following:

**Client Call To Function**

Removed the headers from the fetch options completely rather than setting the content type as application/json. By default the fetch request content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

```
const validateImageFormFetchOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
   formInputs: formInputs
  })
}

fetch('https://project-url.cloudfunctions.net/apiValidateImageForm', validateImageFormFetchOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(serverErrors => {console.log(serverErrors)});
```

**Firebase Function**

Explicitly parsed the request body because it is now received as a text string.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const validateImageForm = require('./library/validate-image-form');

exports.apiValidateImageForm = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
    validateImageForm(body.formInputs, body.imageStatus).then((data) => {
      res.status(200).send(data);
    });
  });
});
```