# Firebase Cloud Function executing twice when triggered over HTTP

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Cloud Functions into my Ionic 3 App. The goal is to create a cloud function that will create a user using the admin SDK.

However, when triggering this function over HTTP it will execute twice only when passing data to it, if I just call the function with no data it executes once as intended.

Cloud Function Code:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  console.log(request.body);
  response.status(200).send('Hello from Firebase!');
});
```

HTTP Request:

```js
axios.post(functionURL, {
  data: 'some data'
})
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The HTTP request above works as intended and I see "Hello from Firebase!
" only once in the console, however when I look at the functions logs it's showing it's being executed twice.

[image]

I'm very new to Firebase Cloud Functions so any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you certain that the client isn't somehow triggering it twice?  HTTP functions come with an at-least-once guarantee per request.  They are either triggered 0 or 1 time with each request.  This type of question gets posted from time to time, and it's always the client.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure too that your client is calling it again somewhere...

Comment: FYI, Cloud Functions might execute multiple times by design. See [this code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-reliability-nodejs/blob/master/idempotency/index.js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solved

Solution found here: [Cloud Functions for Firebase triggering function on CORS preflight request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369912/cloud-functions-for-firebase-triggering-function-on-cors-preflight-request)

As I was sending the data as `application/json` it was triggering a CORS preflight request, which is exactly what was causing the function to execute twice when passing data.

To bypass this, I simply sent the data as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string like this:

```js
const dataStr = JSON.stringify(objectToPass);

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: `data=${dataStr}`
})
```

And then parse the body back into an object in the function like this:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(request.body.data);
```

Comment: Good job on finding the solution to your own question. As soon as you are able to, please mark it as a solution to give more visibility to the question.