# Firebase HTTP Function triggered twice when POST request sent with headers

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-functions

I deployed a [firebase HTTP cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and am experiencing this (unexpected) behavior:

- when I call the function (using POST) from a browser environment with `fetch()`, the function gets triggered twice, one time without any data sent in the body, and another time as I would expect it. In the frontend (chrome network tab) I can only see 1 request, the successfull one.
- this does only happen with POST requests
- this does only happen when the request is sending headers

Is this normal behavior that I dont understand or a potential bug?

### my minimal cloud function

```js
exports.run = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // ALLOW CORS FOR POST REQUEST:
  // => https://stackoverflow.com/a/38259193
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");

  return res.status(200).send({
    status: "ok",
    body: req.body,
    query: req.query,
  }).end();
});
```

### calling from frontend

```js
// example data (not a real one)
const url = "https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/test";
const postData = { x: 1, y: 2 };

// GET request => ✅ works as expected
fetch(url);

// POST request without headers => ✅ works as expected
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(postData),
});

// POST request with headers => ❌ 2 requests get triggered
fetch(url,  {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify(postData),
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is happening because of the [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request):

> A CORS preflight request is a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS) request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood and a server is aware using specific methods and headers.
> ...
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser, and in normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests themselves. It appears when a request is qualified as ["to be preflighted"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) and omitted for [simple requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

As pointed in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369912/cloud-functions-for-firebase-triggering-function-on-cors-preflight-request):

> As long as you’re adding a `Content-Type': 'application/json'` header to the request, the browser is going to automatically on its own do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the request from your code.

Therefore, this is a normal behavior and is not a problem of Cloud Functions for Firebase.

In order to not have the two requests, you can change the header request as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400741/13171940):

```js
// example data (not a real one)
const url = "https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/test";
const postData = { x: 1, y: 2 };
    
// POST request with different header  => ✅ only one request is triggered
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData),
}).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: workes! Thanks for the great explenation and ressources!