# Angular 5 Http Request calls the Rest API's twice

Tags: angular, rest

Can anybody help to find out what i'm doing wrong here. For every rest calls application calls the Rest APIs twice.

But first request doesn't contains request payload and No response, but both requests give same response status code.

Here is my code.

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const body = { userName: username, password: password };
    this. httpClient.post<User>(this.url, body, { headers: this.header })
    .subscribe( data => {
      return data;
 });
```

[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: The browser does that (search for CORS), that's not related to Angular in any way.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the comment But I've added CORS config in the HttpHeaders and server is also configured to handle CORS requests.

Comment: The `OPTIONS` request is to check if the server is OK with the CORS (preflight request) request, the 2nd request is the actual request.

Comment: I think it is related to the preflight request send by the browsers to the server to check everything is okay or not

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Then how I can handle this in my app please provide any suggestions that will be helpful.

Comment: @GavishiddappaGadagi checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Comment: @Dhyey thanks for the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HTTP Preflight Request

**This a normal behavior.**
When you attempt to send data to a server using HTTP methods, the browser sends a preflight request, to ensure that the requested resource and other properties are available and allowed on the backend.

Then if the server accepts the request options, the main request is sent. which is why you are seeing two requests.

So your case is pretty normal and expected.