# Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for post request in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, post, cors

I'm using post request with `HttpClient` like below,

```
return this.httpclient.post<any>(url, body)
            .catch(this.handleError)
```

then it gives me below error,

> Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

Then I tried to add headers like below,

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});


        return this.httpclient.post<any>(url, body, {headers: headers})
            .catch(this.handleError)
```

then it gives me below error,

> **Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403**

- this works fine with `get` request.

what is the reason for this. hope your help with this

Comment: Try to make a request with postman and then see what header parameters work

Comment: yep , it works fine @AshrafulIslam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Answer (score -1):

Try somethink like this :

```
 let body = {dataToSend};
         this.httpClient.post(url, body)
        .subscribe(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
        });
```

It works for me