# Form post giving 405 error

Tags: php, angular, slim-3

I am trying to post data to server. My php side is working fine. When I tried using postman post is working. But from angular I am getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) error:

```
zone.js:2935 OPTIONS http://angularslim.local/public_html/users 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

`Failed to load http://angularslim.local/public_html/users: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`.

My codes are below:
Inside my service I have following code.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
    register(user:User){
        this.http.post("http://angularslim.local/public_html/users", user).subscribe((res: Response) => {
            console.log("inside");
        })
    }
```

And in my php section I do have these lines

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try passing the form value by JSON.stringify(user). I had a same issue before. Later I found that my problem was that.

```
this.http.post("your api url", JSON.stringify(user))
    .subscribe(
    (val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow cross origins AND methods

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Also try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods

In addition, i suggest you to use HttpClient (http is deprecated) and HttpResponse

Comment: Yes, and it only allow origins. Everybody is authorized to send a request. But the question is : What are the HTTP verbs that are open for that user ? This is why i think you need Access-Control-Allow-Methods

Comment: I have header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');

Answer (score 0):

If you use Slim, this is mostly because your Javascript code sends HTTP OPTIONS request while there is no route that handle HTTP OPTIONS.

You need to add a route that handle OPTIONS request or modify any Javascript code that cause [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) to be sent (by making it a simple request. Take a look at this question [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)).

To add route that handle OPTIONS

```
$app->options('/users', function ($request, $response, $args) {
     //do something here
]);
```

More information:

- [Slim Router documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html)
- [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)