# Post works only after a empty get request

Tags: node.js, linux, express, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote a simple server

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
app.post('/', function(req, res){
   res.send('hi')
})
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

I deployed it on the server post don't responding till I send a get request to it
what is the problem?
It works on localhost but not on the server

Server OS is ubuntu 16.04
I know it's on port 3000 and I know it's a post method so I send post request please don't mention it.

There is no problem with code I think problem is related to Ubuntu. Any changes should I make?

Comment: How did you send your post request?

Comment: I sent it via Postman

Comment: Your code works just fine, I've just tried with `curl -X POST` and with Postman, I get the "hi" response in both cases. Are you sending your POST request to port 3000 ?

Comment: I said it works on localhost but on the server it works only after I send any get request

Comment: What do you get when you make a `POST` request for the first time?

Comment: Nothing postman keeps sending no response and server is not logging anything

Comment: How are you deploying it? Share the domain please.

Comment: any chance you're on an https environment? perhaps you need to do a preflight request first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954326/3194525

Comment: @maaw No I don't use https.