# Post Request become in Options Request

Tags: angular, typescript, request

My problem is in my api Angular 6. Once the interceptors are created when send POST request these become in OPTIONS request.

What is the problem ?

This is the code of one Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
import { Perfil } from '../Entities/Perfil';
// import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsuariosService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private config: AppConfig) { }

  private per = new Perfil(1);

  getPerfiles() {
    return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + 'perfiles/Buscar/', this.per);
  }


}
```

this image will help us in this problem:

[image]

Regards!

Comment: `OPTIONS` is the special request method when you trying to access resources from different domain than you server. It involves CORS. Please read more here - [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Answer (score 1):

This is a CORS issue and like lomboboo said `OPTIONS` is a special request made to server to ask what can I do and am I allowed to access content?

In order to provide the fix, in your server (backend) you need to implement CORS headers and allow for `POST` and any other operations you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
//**need to pass header in your post api**


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

 getPerfiles() {
    return this.http.post(this.config.apiUrl + 'perfiles/Buscar/', this.per,httpOptions).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      }, error => console.log('There was an error: '));


};
  }
```

Comment: I test this option and in my context (Angular 6 and .Net Framework) did not work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yeahhh! . I knew that they were the cors, and did implement in the back, but bad.
The solutions i whas implement is this:
*(using .Net Framework 4 )*

*Inside of WebApiConfig.cs*

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
         }
```

thanks **lomboboo** and **Mike**, were this very help!