# How to Configure Angular 6 with .NET Core 2 to allow CORS from any host?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors

I have a simple Angular App running locally on 4200 i am testing with a web api running locally on 5000 using .net core. My startup.cs has CORS configured correctly to allow everything i believe.

In the ConfigureServices section i have:
`services.AddCors();`

In the Configure section i have:

`app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());`

However when i try and hit my webapi i still get this in the browser.

> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I have looked at the other answers and they all seem to have this or similar variations that i have tried with no change. Not sure what else i need to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code snippet in the method ConfigureServices. Edit this for allowing only custom headers.

```
// Add service and create Policy with options
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
        });
```

Add the following in Configure method

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Add 'EnableCors' attribute to the controller.

```
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize i also needed to add the EnableCors attribute to the controller. I did that and everything worked.

Comment: You do not need to add EnableCors attribute to the controller if it is enabled globally.

Comment: @randydaddis It is required if we have multiple policies, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan I am able to make CORs requests to controllers (derived from ControllerBase) which are not configured with the 'EnableCors' attribute. Please refer to the Startup.cs class in my answer below for the way that I configure CORS policies globally.

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: Work for me. Tks a lot

Answer (score 12):

## Possible Issues:

- In your `startup.cs.Configure()` method, does `app.UseCors()` precede `app.useMVC()`?
- Does the Http Request URL contain a trailing slash `(/)`?
- Does the Http Request include Credentials?
- Is the browser receiving a Http Response from the API?
- Does the Response include a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header?
- When you send the request from Postman, does the Http Response include the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header as well as a body containing the data?

## Gotchas

Firefox requires a certificate to be installed for your API in order to send Http Request utilizing the HTTPS protocol.

Test your API with Postman and your browser Developer Tool. Notice 2 Http requests. The Http 200 is a “pre-flight” to see what CORS options are available.

- If your API (.NET) throws a `HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)`, it will return a developer exception page and Postman will display a `“no ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource”` message - **this is mis-leading**.
- The actual problem in this case is that the developer exception page cannot be returned from the server to a client (browser) running on a different Origin.

## I would like to *respectfully* point out the following:

- The ***CORS specification*** states that setting origins to '*' (all origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present.
- `AllowAnyOrigin()` is not recommended in production unless you intend to allow anyone to utilize your API AND you will not implement credentials.
- You do not need to configure CORS at the controller level with the `EnableCors` attribute when utilizing multiple CORS policies.
- Configuring multiple CORS policies with ASP.NET Core is easy(**see tutorial below**)

## The following articles are worth reviewing:

[ASP.NET Core 2.2 does not permit allowing credentials with AllowAnyOrigin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

[Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

### key points (tldr;):

- CORS Middleware must precede any defined endpoints in your app configuration.
- The URL must be specified without a *trailing slash `(/)`*.
- If the browser sends credentials but the response doesn't include a
  valid **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials** header, the browser doesn't
  expose the response to the app, and the cross-origin request fails.
- The CORS specification also states that setting origins to "*" (all
  origins) is invalid if the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is
  present.
- If a browser supports CORS, it sets these headers automatically for cross-origin requests.
- If the response doesn't include the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header, the cross-origin request fails.

---

## CORS Tutorial: (2) Angular Clients + ASP.NET Core

1. Create Visual Studio Solution

   ```
   md c:\s\a
   cd c:\s\a
   c:\s\a>dotnet new sln -n solutionName
   ```
2. Create ASP.NET Core Project

   ```
   c:\s\a>md s
   c:\s\a>cd s
   c:\s\a\s>dotnet new webapi -o api -n api
   ```
3. API Launch Settings and CORS Configuration

**launchSettings.json**

> Clone Development Profile to Staging Profile

```
{
"$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
"iisSettings": {
"windowsAuthentication": false,
"anonymousAuthentication": true,
"iis": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:myIISApiPortNumber",
    "sslPort": myIISApiSSLPortNumber
},
"iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:myIISExpressApiPortNumber",
    "sslPort": myIISExpressApiSSLPortNumber
}
},
"profiles": {
"Development (IIS Express)": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "api/values",
    "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    }
},
"Staging (IIS Express)": {
    "commandName": "IISExpress",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "api/values",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:myIISExpressApiSSLPortNumber;http://localhost:myIISExpressApiPortNumber",
    "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
    }
},
"Production (IIS)": {
    "commandName": "IIS",
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "launchUrl": "api/values",
    "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
    },
    "applicationUrl": "https:localhost:myIISApiSSLPortNumber;http://localhost:myIISApiPortNumber"
}
}
}
```

**startup.cs**

> Add CORS Configuration

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public IServiceCollection _services { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _services = services;
        RegisterCorsPolicies();
        services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseCors("DevelopmentCorsPolicy");
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            app.UseCors("StagingCorsPolicy");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseCors("ProductionCorsPolicy");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(); // CORS middleware must precede any defined endpoints
    }

    private void RegisterCorsPolicies()
    {
        string[] localHostOrigins = new string[] {
        "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:3200"};

        string[] stagingHostOrigins= new string[] {
        "http://localhost:4200"};

        string[] productionHostOrigins = new string[] {
        "http://yourdomain.net", "http://www.yourdomain.net",
        "https://yourdomain.net", "https://www.yourdomain.net"};

        _services.AddCors(options =>    // CORS middleware must precede any defined endpoints
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DevelopmentCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(localHostOrigins)
                        .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
            options.AddPolicy("StagingCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(stagingHostOrigins)
                        .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
            options.AddPolicy("ProductionCorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
                        .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        //options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        //    builder =>
        //    {
        // WARNING: ASP.NET Core 2.2 does not permit allowing credentials with AllowAnyOrigin() 
        // cref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
            //        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            //               .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
            //    });
            //options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificMethods",
            //    builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
            //               .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "HEAD");
            //    });
            //options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificHeaders",
            //    builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
            //               .WithHeaders("accept", "content-type", "origin", "x-custom-header");
            //    });
            //options.AddPolicy("ExposeResponseHeaders",
            //    builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
            //               .WithExposedHeaders("x-custom-header");
            //    });
            //options.AddPolicy("AllowCredentials",
            // WARNING: ASP.NET Core 2.2 does not permit allowing credentials with AllowAnyOrigin() cref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio
            //    builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
            //               .AllowCredentials();
            //    });
            //options.AddPolicy("SetPreflightExpiration",
            //    builder =>
            //    {
            //        builder.WithOrigins(productionHostOrigins)
            //               .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2520));
            //    });
        });
    }
}
```

4. Start Debugging API with **Development (IIS Express) profile**

**Set breakpoint on `ValuesController.Get()`**

5. Test API with Postman:

   `https://localhost:myApiPortNumber/api/values`

   - **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header and values should be in response
6. Create Angular application

   ```
   c:\s\a\s>ng new Spa1 --routing (will automatically create Spa folder)
   ```
7. Start Spa1 application

   ```
   c:\s\a\s>cd Spa1
   c:\s\a\s\Spa1>Ng serve
   ```
8. Browse to http://localhost:4200/

   - Spa1 should start successfully
9. Implement CORs in Spa1

**app.module.ts**

> - Import HttpClientModule

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

> - Import HttpClient
> - Add `getValues()` method with CORS Request

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Spa1';
  values: any;
  apiUrl: string = environment.apiUrl;
  valuesUrl = this.apiUrl + "values";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
  }
  getValues() {
    this.http.get(this.valuesUrl).subscribe(response => {
      this.values = response;
  }, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<h2>Values</h2>
<p *ngFor="let value of values">
  {{value}}
</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://localhost:myApiPortNumber/api/'
};
```

10. Start Spa1 application

    ```
    c:\s\a\s\Spa1>Ng serve
    ```
11. Browse to http://localhost:4200/

    - Chrome & Edge: should successfully make CORs requests now
    - Safari: I have not tested
    - Firefox: may block request due to un-trusted certificate.

One way of remediating the Firefox block:

> FireFox | Options | Privacy & Security | Security | Certificates |
>   [View Certificates] :
>
> Certificate Manager | [Add Exception]:
>
> ```
>    add localhost
> ```

---

### CORS Test

1. Clone Spa1

   ```
   c:\s\a\s>xcopy /s /i Spa1 Spa2
   ```
2. Refactor title of Spa2

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Spa2';
}
```

3. Start Spa2 application on **port 3200**

   ```
   c:\s\a\s\Spa2>ng serve --port 3200
   ```
4. Browse to http://localhost:3200/

   - The values array should render on the web page
5. Stop Debugging API with Development (IIS Express) profile
6. Start Debugging API with **Staging (IIS Express) profile**
7. Browse to http://localhost:4200/

   - The values array **should render** on the web page.
8. Browse to http://localhost:3200/

   - The values array **should not render** on the web page.
9. inspect Http Response with Developer Tools:

   - **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header and values should not be in response

Comment: I've lost a whole day on this one. Thanks for that. Very well explained!

Answer (score 2):

Register cors in services

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

add cors middleware

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem but i my case i had **windowsauthentification**.

@RandyDaddis pointed me to the right direction. 
You can't use '*' if authentification is set.

But this doesn't solve the hole problem (and for me '*' is not a good option).

I had to changed from windowsAuthentication **only** to a **mixed mode** (where anonymousAuthentication is also enabled) because the [preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it) was not sending the credentials.

This was already an discussed issue by [asp](https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/60).

Important is that you add this to your **startup.cs** in the **ConfigureServices** function to ensure all your controllers are still under authorization-policy:

```
 ...
 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        })...
```