# Django REST: OPTIONS request is registered as PUT

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-method

Whenever the browser sends an OPTIONS request, Django REST registers that as a PUT request.

I was writing my permission code when I noticed it. I use the default request parameter that is passed into the `def has_object_permission( self, request, view, obj ):`.

Using `request.method` will return the correct request method for every request except for OPTIONS.
However, when I use `request.method` in a my `get_permission( self, request, view ):` function in a different part of the project, correct response is returned. Could there be something wrong with the `has_object_permission()` function?

Currently I just check if the request is PUT, as I believe PUT requests are not used by Django anyway. But it would be nice if I could use the actual name instead.

My Django REST version is `3.9.0`

Answer (score 0):

OPTIONS requests are often used for what are called "pre-flight" requests in Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).  This is not anything wrong with `has_object_permission()`, it's just that these pre-flight requests are probably not intended to handled by your view.  There is a more detailed answer in this SO post:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954326/784648

Comment: I understand what OPTIONS is, and I already have middleware that handles CORS. However Django still handles them and returns some data about that endpoint. It's not bad, but what's annoying is that OPTIONS triggers `has_object_permisssion()` method, in which I check authentication. Is there a way to prevent GenericAPIView from checking object permissions if the request is OPTIONS ?