# Angular http.get headers not being recognized

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, sugarcrm

I am building an angular 6 application that sends a `get` request to the server through a `REST API`. The URL takes in a few headers and returns the required data, and has been successfully tested on PostMan. Here is the screenshot showing the headers needed by the server:

[image: Post Man image]

I am trying to create a function using `http.get` in order to retrieve these records in my application. I have created a service called `listService` that would take in the module name and prepare a header object. The service would then call an `adapterService` (containing my `get` function), that would prepare the headers and fire the request to the server. Unfortunately instead of getting a valid response I receive the following error:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:13170:51)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2743:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42628:33)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2742:36)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2510:47)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2818:34)
>       at invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3862:14)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3888:17)"

Upon adding the logs from the server I noticed the headers that were being sent in the request:

```
 Wed Mar 20 11:37:43 2019 [21570][-none-][FATAL] Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Accept] => application/json, text/plain, */*
    [Origin] => http://evil.com/
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
    [Referer] => http://localhost:4200/profile
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
    [If-None-Match] => d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
)
```

The data I'm sending is not even being added to the headers! I'm not sure why this is happening. I've checked the docs to see if I'm adding the `http headers` the wrong way, and have console logged at various points and everything seems to be fine **up until** the call to `http.get`. I really don't understand what's going on here.

Here is my code:

**listService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtService } from 'src/app/services/jwt/jwt.service';
import { AdapterService } from 'src/app/services/adapter/adapter.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';

/**
* This property contains the attributes of the environment configuration.
*/
const API = environment.api;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListService {

  /**
  * Constructor to initialize the jwt service, adapter service, logger and translation pipe
  */
  constructor(private adapter: AdapterService,
    private jwt: JwtService,
    private translate: TranslatePipe,
    private logger: NGXLogger,
    private toaster: ToastrService) { }

  /**
   * This method initialzes the parameters for the the Get call.
   *
   * @param  username
   * @param  password
   * @return
   */
  initializeParameters(module: string): any {
    let token = this.jwt.getToken();
    let params = {
      "module": module,
      "platform": API.platform,
      "oauth_token": token
    };
    return params;
  }

  /**
  * This method sends request for listing relevant data from module
  */
  listData(module: string) {
    let params = this.initializeParameters(module);
    this.adapter.get('customPortalApi/listRecords', params)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.logger.warn(response);
        },
        error => {
          let errmsg = this.translate.transform("pages[login_page][responses][error][" + error.error + "]");
          this.toaster.error(errmsg); console.log(error);
        }
      )
  }
}
```

**adapterService (header and get functions)**

```
private requestHeaders(path: string, headerData: any) {
    let headers;
    if (path !== 'customPortalApi/customToken') {
        headers = new HttpHeaders();
        for(let key in headerData){
          let value = headerData[key];
          headers = headers.append(key, value);
        }
      }
        return headers;
    }

  /**
   * This method generates the GET api call.
   *
   * @param path
   * @param params
   * @method get
   * @return
   */
    get(path: string, data: any, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable < any > {
    let headers = this.requestHeaders(path, data); 
    return this.http.get(`${API_URL}${path}`, headers)
            .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
    }
```

**dummy component (for call)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ListService} from 'src/app/services/list/list.service';

/**
* This component is for testing
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dummy',
  templateUrl: './dummy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dummy.component.scss']
})
export class DummyComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private list: ListService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.list.listData("accounts");
  }
}
```

**EDIT** for anyone who wants to get an idea of how the header object looks like before making the call to `http.get`:

[image: picture]

**Another Edit**
Could it be that CORS may be causing an issue? I have set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to "*". Here is my network activity once the I made changes proposed:

[image: result]

The `REST` service is being hit but it is not redirecting me to my API

The headers being logged on the server when I send via postman are:

```
Wed Mar 20 12:52:50 2019 [21570][1][FATAL] Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [module] => Accounts
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [oauth_token] => 9efe19d4d2ec3b557b4d0588a3f74d5d3cc0ed46
    [platform] => base
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
    [Postman-Token] => 3ddc88e1-e7a8-700f-580b-801da5f0adde
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, br
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9
    [Cookie] => download_token_base=e790d5a8-17a4-4110-98ab-a6648a0ef385
)
```

And these **are** working properly

Comment: Try passing the headers as `this.http.get(`${API_URL}${path}`, {headers: headers})`

Comment: Hi @xyz, made the changes but now the call isn't even being made to the server and the console displays the following error: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get(path: string, data: any, params: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable < any > {
let httpOptions ={headers: this.requestHeaders(path, data)}; 
return this.http.get(`${API_URL}${path}`, httpOptions)
        .pipe(catchError(this.formatErrors));
}
```

Try it like this. You need to pass an option object that contains the headers property.

https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers

Comment: Hi @Qellson, made the changes but now the call isn't even being made to the server and the console displays the following error: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404`. Similar solution was given by @xyz just moments ago in the comments

Comment: Maybe this will help @noobdev :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it