# How to post form data in angular?

Tags: angular, cors, angular7, form-data, angular-httpclient

I am trying to post one of the form data to specific server which is CORS disabled that means it will only accept POST method and dis-allowed OPTIONS preflight request which is completely understandable but one of the post says that if request is Simple Request (POST with content type =application/x-www-form-urlencoded, )it should not create problem but i am still getting error of

### Actual Error on console..

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://****.****.com/hpm/launchTransnoxScreen.hpm' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

--

Could you please help me identify the issue ? I am completely new to angular and just started exploring.

[Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Already checked above URL

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Patient } from '../model/patient';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SignupService {
    private url: string = "https://stagemc.transnox.com/hpm/launchTransnoxScreen.hpm";

      private httpHeadersVar = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Accept': 'text/html'
        })
      };
      patientFormData: Patient;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      callThP(data) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('myKey1', 'some value 1');
        formData.append('myKey2', 'some value 2');
        formData.append('myKey3', 'true');

        this.http.post(this.url, formData, this.httpHeadersVar).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res);
          },
          err => console.log(err)
        );
      }
    }
```

Below sample of html is working fine individually when we clicked on button.

It connects to host and revert with sample page.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="hppForm" name="hppForm" method="POST" action=" https://stagecp.transnox.com/hpm/launchTransnoxScreen.hpm">
            <input name="uniqueID" id="uniqueID" type="hidden" value="XXX3" />
            <input name="deviceID" id="deviceID" type="hidden" value="test_deviceID"/>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In which language you have made api.
In api configuration you have to allow CORS

Comment: Hi Shiv, as i mentioned earlier this should be considered as simple request and should not send Options method . Thanks

Comment: @DnyaneshwarMuley I believe by `Options` you are talking about the Preflight.  And you are saying that a `Simple Request`, as defined by HTTP, includes a `POST` method with a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  I think your question is perfectly valid, and should not trigger a CORS exception.  Others mention the `API`. But as you know, the resource you are calling is irrelevant.  The Browser/caller is the one who enforces CORS, not the resource you are calling.  So if the browser determines it is not a `Simple Request` it throws that exception.

Comment: That all said, I believe the issue is with the HTTP packages you are using (Angular HTTP perhaps).  They may be adding additional headers that break the rules of a `Simple Request`.  I don't have the documentation, but one example might be something like `Accept-Encoding`.  But again, I'm not a master of the rules of `Simple Request`, though I'm pretty sure it's because it's adding headers that break the rules.

Answer (score -1):

I think HTTP Headers are not working: Try this:

`Implement this:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};


this.http.post<any>
      (`Your URL`, formData).subcribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
```

If this is not working then there might be chance that your API is not allowing the CORS.

Comment: Hi Venkata, actually it's not a api call. Thats why i am not using json header. Its a simple html form submission and if all the values of form is correct then server will redirect to their own page. Please check the sample html i mentioned above. BTW thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

you can follow this link:

https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/

You should also check your backend language where you have created API, there enable CORS