# axios making an empty request then the correct request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

When i try to make a request to my server the client send two requests, the first with an empty `body`, and the second with the correct body

this is my server file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const authMiddleware = require('./app/middlewares/auth.middleware');

const db = require('./config/db');

app.use(authMiddleware);

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

db.then(res => {
  require('./app/routes')(app);
});

server.listen(3210, () => {
  console.log('\x1b[0m', 'Backend escutando e enviando na porta 3210');
});
```

this is the route file

```
const userController = require('../controllers/user.controller');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/sign-up', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const signUpData = await userController.signUp(req.body);
      res.status(200).json(signUpData.user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      res.status(400).json(error);
    }
  });

  app.post('/sign-in', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const signInData = await userController.signIn(req.body);
      res.header('x-auth-token', signInData.token);
      res.status(200).json(signInData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(400).json(error);
    }
  });
};
```

here is my axios configuration on my react project

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3210';

export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: apiUrl,
  headers: {
    common: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
});
```

the function where i do the request

```
export const signIn = data => {
  return api
    .post(`/sign-in`, data)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

> This error only occours when the request is made via client, when i
>   use postman everything works fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it

Comment: no, its not that
when i make the request, it send two OPTIONS and two POSTs

Comment: where and how are you using your signIn function in the client?

Comment: please show how are you calling signIn in your component ?

Comment: it is triggered by an onSubmit event  

`const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await signIn({ email, senha });
  };`