# React JS - Fetch with custom method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a web app with react, and when I try to request to my API using a custom method (AUTH) it says I requested with the OPTIONS method. 
here is my code

```
    await fetch(apiUrl + '/' + formState.values.email + '/' + formState.values.password,{method: 'AUTH', body: ""}).then(async (res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        await res.json().then((data) => {
          localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(data.user_data));
          localStorage.setItem('user_auth', JSON.stringify(data.user_auth));
        });
      }
    }).then(() => {
      router.history.push('/');
    })
```

but in by backend service it says different, here is the screenshot of my backend
[image]

Can Anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Comment: your question is not clear could you show the log and response json as well?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable CORS in your Server Application to handle [origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin) for external 
requests.