# CORS Missing Allow Origin

Tags: vue.js, cors, nuxt.js, django-cors-headers

My server (written with `Django`) is running at `http://localhost:8000`.

The `Nuxt` application is running at `http://localhost:3000`.

When I send a request (like `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/position/`) to the server, I get the following error in the `firefox` browser.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/position/.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

**Firefox:**

[image: error in firefox network tab]

**Chrome:**

[image: Error in chrome network tab]

I saw [this link](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/) and [this](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module#readme) but I do not know where the problem comes from?

Below is a section of my `nuxt.config.js` file.

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
],
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/', 
},
```

And function that I'm sending a request:

```
async getAllPosition() {
    this.loading_position = true;
    await this.$axios.get('user/position/').then(response => {
          this.position = response.data;
    }).finally(() => {
         this.loading_position = false;
        })
 }
```

I think it's about proxy, but i don't know how to config it.

Comment: This document can help you  https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@BananaLama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15071496/bananalama) and [@TMFLGR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14721231/tmflgr) mentioned in their answers:

I need to specify `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in my `Django` server to allow request across origins. For this purpose, I used `django-cors-headers` [package](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/).

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Then allowed it in the `settings.py` section and the results were well returned.

```
// settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS  = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error message reveals: You need to specify a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header in your Server to allow your request across origins. (yea ::3000 and ::8000 are different origins). Modern Browsers will fire a options (pre-flight) request to check the Access-* headers when requesting another origin. You must answer those `OPTIONS` requests with at least a Access-Control header.
`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:3000` should be fine for  development.

More about CORS and the Browser OPTIONS Request here:
https://enable-cors.org/
[Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a forward proxy to handle cross-domain

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  ...
  proxy: {
    '/api': { 
      target: 'http://localhost:8000',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/api',
        changeOrigin: true
      }    
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @TMFLGR mentioned:
Add a OPTION-Request handler to your server and specify a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header`. Proxy is fine for development but in production you should not do this.