# Allow CORS between ReactJS and Flask Backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, cors, flask-cors

I'm having an issue with CORS. I've implemented my RESTful backend using Flask and the frontend with React JS. When I attempt to make any request by calling an API, I'm blocked by CORS.

This is the API.js file

```
const APIURL = new URL('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/');

async function logIn(credentials) {
    let response = await fetch(APIURL + 'login', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        const user = await response.json();
        return user;
    } else {
        const errDetail = await response.json();
        throw errDetail.message;
    }
}
```

**Server side we have:**

main.py:

```
from src import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True )
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "db"
DB_USERNAME = "root"
DB_PASSWORD = "root"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, origins='http://localhost:3000', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'])
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
    app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
    app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("JWT_SECRET_KEY")
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'mysql://{DB_USERNAME}:{DB_PASSWORD}@localhost/{DB_NAME}'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    jwt = JWTManager(app)
    db.init_app(app)


    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/api')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/api')

    from .models import User

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return app
```

and auth.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_cors import cross_origin

from .models import User
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from . import db
from flask_login import login_user, login_required, logout_user, current_user
from flask_jwt_extended import create_access_token
from flask_jwt_extended import get_jwt_identity
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)


@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def login():
    data = request.json
    print(data)
    email = data.get('email')
    password = data.get('password')

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.pe_id)
            return jsonify(access_token=access_token), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Incorrect user or password, try again.'}), 400
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Incorrect user or password, try again.'}), 400
```

I continue to obtain this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

On the server terminal I see:

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 134-368-434
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Nov/2023 14:51:38] "OPTIONS /api/login HTTP/1.1" 415 -
```

I have tryed the simply case reported by doc of flask-cors so i have tried todo that:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
```

but nothing changed.
After i tried also to specify more info like that:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app, origins='http://localhost:3000', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'])
```

but also in this case still nothing.

I have also tried to add OPTIONS method to login api:

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def login():
```

[Network screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni3G8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, your server needs to reply with the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header if you're goign to pass credentials. According to the [`flask_cors` documentation](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html#extension), to do that you need to specify `supports_crentials = True` in your call (it defaults to False):

> `supports_credentials` (`bool`) –
>
> Allows users to make authenticated requests. If true, injects the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header in responses. This allows cookies and credentials to be submitted across domains.
>
> note: This option cannot be used in conjunction with a ‘*’ origin
>
> Default : `False`

So:

```
CORS(
    app,
    origins='http://localhost:3000',
    methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    supports_credentials=True
)
```

---

Note: Once you've fixed that, you may start getting a 415 error because the `login` handler doesn't distinguish between `POST` and `OPTIONS`, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012921/i-get-options-method-instead-of-post-in-flask) to see how to handle that (basically: check the method before trying to read the request body).