# FLASK + VUE: Blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, cors, web-development-server

This is my myFetch.ts:

```
const API_ROOT = import.meta.env.VITE_API_ROOT as string;

export function rest(url: string, body?: unknown, method?: string, headers?: HeadersInit){

    return fetch(url, {
        method: method ?? (body ? "POST" : "GET"),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            ...headers
        },
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined
    })
        .then(response => response.ok 
            ? response.json()
            : response.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err))    )
}

export function api(action: string, body?: unknown, method?: string, headers?: HeadersInit){
    return rest(`${API_ROOT}/${action}`, body, method, headers);
}
```

My app.py function includes this CORS line:

```
CORS(app)
```

And also properly includes the blueprint for the route I am trying to access. When I use Postman, the route works.

I tried manually setting CORS headers like this:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
    return response
```

And I've also tried adding a decorator to my route:

```
@cross_origin(origin="http://localhost:5173", supports_credentials=True)
```

I've tried adding the OPTIONS method manually to my rest function in the method:

```
    const actualMethod = method === "OPTIONS" ? "OPTIONS" : method ?? (body ? "POST" : "GET");
```

But nothing is working! I still get the error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ports/getports' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

And this one:
GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/ports/getports net::ERR_FAILED

And then a Failed to Fetch error.

If anyone has any insight that would be fantastic, thank you!

SOLVED:
[I get [OPTIONS] method instead of [POST] in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012921/i-get-options-method-instead-of-post-in-flask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I get \[OPTIONS\] method instead of \[POST\] in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012921/i-get-options-method-instead-of-post-in-flask)