# GET requests blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-security, amazon-cloudfront

I have deployed a full-stack ecommerce application to AWS. This app consists of an Angular frontend and a Spring Boot application that exposes certain REST API endpoints, such as Products and Product Categories.

- I've configured the backend so that one API in particular, Orders, is only accessible to applications that have an access token.
- In my Angular frontend, I've implemented an interceptor to add an access token to the request for the Orders API.

My REST API and Angular app are each fronted by a CloudFront distribution:

- The domain for the Angular app's CF dist. is **https://myshop.com**
- The domain for the CF dist. that exposes my REST APIs is *https://myshopapi.com/api*

For the REST API dist., I configured CORS to allow GET requests from all origins.

I visit **https://myshop.com** and click the Orders link, thus making a GET request to the Orders API so I can retrieve a customer's orders, but no orders are listed. I check the Dev Tools console to discover the following errors:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myshopapi.com/api/orders' from origin 'https://myshop.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

```
GET https://myshopapi.com/api/orders net:: ERR_FAILED
```

The problem is that when **https://myshop.com** sends GET requests to my other REST APIs, I don't have ANY issues. I only get these errors when I try to access the Orders API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preflight request is `Options` NOT `Get`
you should configured CORS to allow `GET` and `Options` requests from all origins
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

see also [Why is an OPTIONS request sent and can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it)

Comment: Thanks! It works now! I just had to reconfigure my REST API CloudFront's response header policy to CORS-With-Preflight.