OPTIONS Request made to domain root (/) on ddev nginx throws a 405 - We see access.log but the request is not forwarded to index.php
Edit
Corrected a couple of assumptions with more testing (and altered title to reflect). The issue seems to be specific to the nginx config on DDev, with the server not correctly passing "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" requests to the web root (despite all pathing and postman requests working fine).
further edit
Refined question to best be found for those with the same issue.

Q: Whats happening?
Requests OPTIONS made from a JavaScript frontend, using Axios, to the root level domain (e.g. https://domain.ddev.site) fail with a CORS 405 OPTIONS not allowed error, despite all OPTIONS requests to paths working fine.
Q: You can't be allowing the OPTIONS request then
That's just it, I am. All pathed requests work fine (i.e. https://domain.ddev.site/path). When making a request to the domain root, Axios throws the 405 for options but the request never reaches the index.php file. We see the access request in the nginx access.log
Q: Any other info?
Axios version: "axios": "^0.21.1",

We're stuck with Node 16 for now (no, thats not going to change).
Testing with ddev and Xdebug to watch the requests
Nothing in logs
Console throws CORS:


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain.ddev.site/' from origin 'http://domain.ddev.site:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


Appears to maybe be an nginx issue.


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954037/why-is-an-options-request-sent-and-can-i-disable-it

Its really not a duplicate...

The issue it turns out is specific to the nginx configuration being used with DDev.
the inclution of the $uri/ element in the location try_files configuration results in a failier to correctly route OPTIONS requests made to the base domain onwards to the application.
As it turns out, $uri/ is in general not required for most modern web applications due to the almost ubiquitous use of a single exposed index file to handle all requests made to an application. As such, it can be safely removed, resolving the issue.
See Discussion here: https://github.com/serversideup/docker-php/issues/89
The specific fix is simple.
In the .ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf file change:
location / {
    absolute_redirect off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

to
location / {
    absolute_redirect off;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

You will also need to remove the ##ddev generated comment at the top of the file to prevent the file being overwritten again.
Then restart ddev
ddev restart
and that should solve the issue.

We'll want to reflect this in DDEV's default nginx configuration, but you'll need to say what project type you were using to be able to help with that.

@rfay - I've asked the dev that set the original base project up to confirm (We're UK time, so he wont be on for another 9/10 hours or so) but the DDEV config lists the project_type as simply 'php', if that helps.

That means it's using the simplest config for nginx. I think several of the project-specific nginx configs already have this set up the way you want. It will be interesting to find out what the actual CMS type you're using is. You can browse the various configs at https://github.com/ddev/ddev/tree/master/pkg/ddevapp/webserver_config_assets

@rfay the project is a proprietary SaaS framework, though the general setup is common enough. All requests go to the root index.php, which boots the app and then handles the paths accordingly. so project type of 'PHP' is correct here.
I'll have a look through the other cms configs and see if anything is a better fit

A PR to update https://github.com/ddev/ddev/blob/master/pkg/ddevapp/webserver_config_assets/nginx-site-php.conf would be very welcome. I think that's descended from an early drupal config.

@rfay will do when i get half a moment :)
