# How to call python function from safari extension

Tags: javascript, python, safari, safari-extension

I am creating a safari extension and in the backend I am using python to save the data. But I am unable to call the python function, it is giving me this error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is my python function url:http://localhost:8000/polls/add

I am using jquery/ajax to call the python function

This is my script code:

```
var action_url ="localhost:8000/polls/add";
params = 'contact_name=abc&contact_email=abc@gmail.com&content=here is content';
$.ajax({
    url: action_url,
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Ori‌​gin', 'localhost');
    },
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(params),
    error: function (e) { alert('error = '+e) },
    success: function (data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Hi GGG,
Thanks for your reply.
Ok, edited

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issue. Try to disable it from Safari, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari) maybe it helps.

Comment: Hi Vitalie Maldur,
Yes, I have CORS issue, I checked your reply but it doesn`t help me.

Comment: Did you try to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the response from your server? not on your request.

Comment: Yes, I set like this, this is my def

def helloworld():
    resp = make_response()
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp
    
getting the same error