# The CORS policy has prohibited access to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: reactjs, django, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-implementation, agora

I'm using django code for the app server, which is available at https://github.com/AgoraIO/Agora-Chat-API-Examples/tree/main/chat-app-server-django, and this for the web SDK, which is available at https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/AgoraChat-web. i am getting the CORS error. Do I need to enable any Agora settings. A call can also be put up, right?
Getting this error :
The CORS policy has prohibited access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8000/app/user/register' from origin 'http://localhost:3000': Preflight response fails access control verification: The requested resource doesn't have a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this package in the console

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

Add it to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'corsheaders',
...]
```

Add it to middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
...]
```

Now add a list of origins to settings.py

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
"https://example.com",
"https://sub.example.com",
"http://localhost:8080",
"http://127.0.0.1:8080"]
```

Also set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL to false.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is local development, you have to disable CORS checking in your browser.

See the posts below

- [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)
- [Disabling same-origin policy in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari/12158217#12158217)